How does systemd RequiresMountsFor behave on a nonexistent directory?
The RequiresMountsFor= option in a systemd units file requires the mount for the specified paths be in place before the unit is started.
As far as I can tell, arguments can be a mount point as well as any directory underneath that mount point. For example, if the zone files for BIND are in /etc/bind and /etc is on its own filesystem, either RequiresMountsFor=/etc or RequiresMountsFor=/etc/bind will achieve the desired outcome: BIND will not start until /etc has been mounted and thus /etc/bind is available.
Now I’m wondering what would happen if RequiresMountsFor= were to specify a nonexistent path. For example, if fstab has entries for / and /etc but nothing underneath /etc, and RequiresMountsFor=/etc/this/path/does/not/exist refers to a path which does not exist in /etc.
Would this cause the unit to wait for /etc to be mounted (as it is the last mount point in the path)? If so, would the unit ultimately start once /etc is mounted, or would it fail because /etc/this/path/does/not/exist is not found?
This might get relevant where units accept parameters, such as postgresql@.service, which has RequiresMountsFor=/etc/postgresql/%I /var/lib/postgresql/%I. If the data files for one cluster are moved away, the second path will point nowhere if the unit is invoked on that cluster.

RequiresMountsFor= is a direct translation to Requires= for the corresponding .mount units, with systemd checking each possible prefix (/, /etc, /etc/postgresql, ...) for existence of a corresponding .mount unit and adding it to the Requires dependencies; prefixes that don't correspond to a .mount unit are skipped.
There is no other checking beyond that, in particular no translation to unit conditions. If you need to check for the existence of a path, use ConditionPathExists= or AssertPathExists=.

What about mounts in /etc/fstab? I did not find any systemd unit files for them – have I just overlooked them (if so, where would they be)? If not, do RequiresMountsFor= play together with /etc/fstab?

They are written to /run/systemd/generator/ every time systemd reloads configuration (on boot and on every daemon-reload), see man systemd-fstab-generator.
